# Change multiple substrings in a text based on other substrings in text with Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, replace, substring

We process M940 bankstatements in our ERP-system but the bank does not provide the statement number in the file (it always states 00001/00001) so I want to put the statement-date where the statement number should be. Each statement has a statement number preceded with code :28C: and a statement date in a line that starts with :60F: such as below.

:28C:**00001/00001**  
:60F:C**220315**EUR140379,24  
:28C:**00001/00001**  
:60F:C**220316**EUR440379,24

How can I get Powershell to change 00001/00001 into the date coming from the :60F: line right after it? In the real thing there are lines with codes before :28C: and after :60F: and maybe even other codes in between. However, there will always be a :60:-line with the date after a :28C: line.

:28C:**220315**  
:60F:C**220315**EUR140379,24  
:28C:**220316**  
:60F:C**220316**EUR440579,58

I already have created some powershell script that adds other neccessary substrings and moves it to a directory depending on the bankaccount mentioned in the file but that part of the script is not relevant for this question therefore not stated here.

I would already be very happy with a link that pushes me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement to read from your file line by line (`-File`) and use regex (regular-expression) pattern matching (`-Regex`):

```
switch -Regex -File file.txt {
  '^:28C:'          { $saved = $_; continue } # save the line and continue
  '^:60F:C(\d+)EUR' { $saved -replace '00001/00001', $Matches[1]; $_ }
  default           { $_ } # unrelated line, pass through
}
```

- `$saved -replace '00001/00001', $Matches[1]` uses the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to replace verbatim string `00001/00001` with what the (first) capture group (`(\d+)`) in the branch condition captured (i.e. the amount, composed of one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`)), as reflected in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) variable and outputs the result.
- The [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) contains the input line at hand, and `; $_` outputs it afterwards.

Comment: Dear mklement0, thank you very, very much. That works beautifully! I read forum postings the whole day on substring-replacement but I would never have come up which such a nice solution.